# JavaFX control stroke styling with only CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a button that I want to draw a custom shape in.

```
.arrow-button {
    -fx-shape: "M 90 50 10 90 10 10 z";
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;
    -fx-fill: #ff0000;
    -fx-stroke : #ff0000;
    -fx-stroke-width: 100;
    -fx-stroke-line-join: round;
    -fx-stroke-line-cap: round;
}
```

[image]

Besides the background color and the shape, stroke css doesn't affect the shape at all, or the color. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS properties `-fx-fill` and `-fx-stroke*` are not applicable to [controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html) (such as buttons), only to [shapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html). See the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled) for details.

The reason `-fx-shape` works with `Button` is because it's defined on `Region`, which is a superclass of `Button` (but not a superclass of `Shape`)

Comment: Actually, I just set your answer to correct because indeed, I could set different shape styles on the components that inherit from the Shape class, but I'm still curious, why does `-fx-shape` still work on Buttons, and some other components? Surely if it can modify the shape, it can set which stroke the shape has?

Comment: @Zee The `-fx-shape` CSS property sets the [`Region#shape`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#shapeProperty) property—it does not mean `Region`s are `Shape`s (different class hierarchies).